# Codename One - container.setScrollVisible(true) in the center of a BorderLayout

Tags: codenameone

I tried to use:

```
container.setScrollableY(true);
container.setScrollVisible(true);
```

The `container` is placed in the the center of a BorderLayout.

The container results scrollable, but the scroll bar is not visible (neither during the scrolling nor in other moments). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scrollbar will only appear if you have enough content within the container and fades out when you don't scroll. Make sure to add enough elements to the container to see it and then try scrolling.